# Convert current time to WebKit/Chrome 17-digit timestamp

Tags: javascript, python, bash, google-chrome, webkit

I'm writing some bash script that parses and modifies multiple preferences and bookmarks of Google Chrome in OS X. Some of the values require 17-digit WebKit timestamp to be provided. For now I've hardcoded it with `13116319200000000` which corresponds to beginning of my workday this Monday in CEST, but it would be great to have this somehow calculated from current system time, as the script will be deployed at different times.

*WebKit timestamp is a 64-bit value for microseconds since Jan 1, 1601 00:00 UTC.* Such conversion in bash on OS X might be impossible, as the built-in version of `data` does not support resolution higher than a second (like `%N`), but maybe some highly-intelligent math would do.

---

Anyway, I've searched the web and found multiple examples on how to convert such timestamp to human readable time, but not the other way around. The best example would be [this website](http://www.epochconverter.com/webkit), that lists python script from some *dpcnull* user:

```
import datetime
def date_from_webkit(webkit_timestamp):
    epoch_start = datetime.datetime(1601,1,1)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=int(webkit_timestamp))
    print epoch_start + delta
inTime = int(raw_input('Enter a Webkit timestamp to convert: '))
date_from_webkit(inTime)
```

and also has this JavaScript on form's action (where `document.we.wk.value` points to that form):

```
function WebkitToEpoch() {
    var wk = document.we.wk.value;
    var sec = Math.round(wk / 1000000);
    sec -= 11644473600;
    var datum = new Date(sec * 1000);
    var outputtext = "<b>Epoch/Unix time</b>: " + sec;
    outputtext += "<br/><b>GMT</b>: " + datum.toGMTString() + "<br/><b>Your time zone</b>: " + datum.toLocaleString();
    $('#resultle1').html(outputtext);
}
```

that looks like it could be easily inverted, but I failed trying.

Interestingly, the site shows current WebKit timestamp, but after examination I believe it's calculated in PHP on server level, so there's no access to it.

I'd be glad if someone could help me with the script I could embed in mine.

---

***Note:*** *Although Google Chrome uses all 17-digits with precise microseconds, I don't really need such resolution. Just like on the linked website, rounding to seconds with last six digits being zeros is perfectly fine. The only important factor - it has to calculate properly.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def date_from_webkit(webkit_timestamp):
    epoch_start = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
    delta = timedelta(microseconds=int(webkit_timestamp))
    return epoch_start + delta


def date_to_webkit(date_string):
    epoch_start = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
    date_ = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    diff = date_ - epoch_start
    seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24
    return '{:<017d}'.format(
        diff.days * seconds_in_day + diff.seconds + diff.microseconds)


# Webkit to date
date_from_webkit('13116508547000000')  # 2016-08-24 10:35:47

# Date string to Webkit timestamp
date_to_webkit('2016-08-24 10:35:47')  # 13116508547000000
```

Comment: Thank You very much for a _lightning fast to the point_ answer! While trying to put Your code into mine I've actually found that `datetime.now()` outputs also precise microseconds (with `%f`), so I've used it to get full resolution available. Luckily, after few tests I've found out that microseconds obviously don't have leading zeros, but thanks to [pyformat](https://pyformat.info) site I discovered `'{:06d}'.format()`. I'll post my final code here.

Answer (score 0):

So after great solution provided by [Tiger-222](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39121470/6751451) I've found out about python's `datetime` microseconds (`%f`) and added it to my final bash script to get full available time resolution and, as a result, the precise WebKit timestamp. Might be helpful for someone, thus final code below:

```
function currentWebKitTimestamp {
    TIMESTAMP="$(python - <<END
from datetime import datetime

def calculateTimestamp():
    epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
    utcnow = datetime.strptime(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    diff = utcnow - epoch
    secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24
    return '{}{:06d}'.format(diff.days * secondsInDay + diff.seconds, diff.microseconds)
print calculateTimestamp()
END)"
    echo $TIMESTAMP
}
echo $(currentWebKitTimestamp)
```

The script embeds python in bash, just as I needed.

---

**Important note:** `diff.microseconds` do not have leading zeros here, so when below 100k, the way they're added they would result in corrupted timestamp, therefore the `{:06d}` format has been added to avoid this.