# Convert current time to WebKit/Chrome 17-digit timestamp in Javascript (I have the answer in Python)

Tags: javascript, python, date, google-chrome, webkit

I need to convert JS current time into WebKit/Chrome 17-digit timestamp, here is the code to do it in Python (I need it in Javascript)

```
def date_to_webkit(date_string):
    epoch_start = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
    date_ = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    diff = date_ - epoch_start
    seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24
    return '{:<017d}'.format(
        diff.days * seconds_in_day + diff.seconds + diff.microseconds)

# Date string to Webkit timestamp
date_to_webkit('2016-08-24 10:35:47')  # 13116508547000000
```

This is from this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/39121470/5546742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the given Python code to JS.

```js
function date_to_webkit(date_string) {
  epoch_start = new Date(1601, 0, 1);
  date_ = new Date(date_string);
  diff = Math.abs(date_ - epoch_start) * 1000;
  return diff;
}
date_string = "2016-08-24 10:35:47";
webkit_string = date_to_webkit(date_string);
console.log(webkit_string);
```

Output:

```
13116508547000000
```

Disclaimer: it passes the given test case. Should be checked for different timezones and different dates.

Comment: Converting your code to a runnable snippet does not produce the output claimed. In Safari it returns NaN, in Firefox (for me) it returns 13116420887000000. The epoch 1 Jan 1601 should be UTC, not local as in this answer. Parsing the timestamp should not be left to the built–in parser as it's implementation dependent (hence NaN in Safari). Even fixing those errors, it will only return the stated value where the host offset is the same as the host that ran the example.

Answer (score 0):

A literal conversion of the PHP code also means manually parsing the string. The OP timestamp format is not supported by ECMA-262, so parsing with the built—in parser is implementation dependent and at least one common browser will treat it as invalid. So it should be manually parsed per the PHP code.

Parsing '2016-08-24 10:35:47' will not return the same time value for all systems as the absence of an offset means it will be parsed as local, so parsed values will differ by the local timezone offset.

According to the linked answer, the epoch is Jan 1, 1601 00:00 UTC which will be a constant (-11644473600000), so there is no need to calculate it every time.

An optimised version of the code is:

```js
function date_to_webkit(date_string) {
  // Parse input timestamp
  let [Y, M, D, H, m, s] = date_string.split(/\W/);
  // Treat timestamp values as local
  // 11644421940000 is the epoch offset constant
  return (new Date(Y, M-1, D, H, m, s).getTime() + 11644421940000) * 1e3;
}

// Convert webkit/Chrome time value to Date
function webkit_to_date(tv) {
  return new Date((tv / 1000) - 11644421940000);
}

let date = '2016-08-24 10:35:47';
let tv = date_to_webkit(date);

console.log('Start date string : ' + date +
          '\nDate as time value: ' + tv +
          '\nTime value as Date: ' + webkit_to_date(tv).toLocaleString('en-CA'));
```